# Chat Room Deletion?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have noticed that no one is really active in [The Playground](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/the-playground) anymore. Should we delete it, Freeze it, or leave it up for a little while longer?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, it is essential that each site has at least one site-specific chat room. It’s there when it’s needed and if the community has nothing to discuss, that’s also ok.

There’s no minimum posts per month or minimum number of users. It’s a communication channel that can be used for those topics that don’t fit in the Q/A format on Main or here on Meta.

I would never take that away from the community.